# Excel SUMPRODUCT with ISNUMBER and TIMEVALUE and LEFT to meet criteria

Tags: excel-formula

In `Cell D$3$:D$38$` I have

```
## Heading ##
Thu Oct-05
Off
Off
Off
Maternity
Off
Off
Off
Off
Off
Off
VACATION
04:00-16:00
04:00-14:00
05:00-14:00
05:00-14:00
06:00-16:00
06:00-15:00
07:00-17:00
07:30-16:30
07:30-16:30
08:00-17:00
08:00-17:00
08:00-18:00
08:00-17:00
08:00-18:00
09:00-18:00
09:30-18:30
10:00-19:00
10:00-19:00
10:30-19:30
10:30-19:30
11:00-20:00
12:00-22:00
13:00-22:00
13:00-22:00
15:00-22:00
```

I used the formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(TIMEVALUE(LEFT($D$3:$D$38,5)))))
```

to successfully obtain the result of 25 cells with number in the specified range but when I try to add a criteria like:
 `>=ISNUMBER(TIMEVALUE(B44))` and `B44` is `4:00 am` and the second criteria `<=ISNUMBER(TIMEVALUE(c44))` `B44` is `5:00 am`
I'm not able to get the result I should that's: **2**

Do you know why it is not working the way it should?
Thank You

Comment: I think you meant B44 contains "4:00 AM" and *C44* contains "5:00 AM". Nevertheless, please paste the entire formula so that we can see what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the formula to this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(TIMEVALUE(LEFT(TEXT($D$3:$D$50,"hh:mm:ss"),5)))))
```

The reason it doesn't recognize `4:00 am` or `5:00 am` is due to `TIMEVALUE` evaluate `time text` and therefore, you need to convert it to time text first.